# Derivations on a Manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

Let $M\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be an $m$-dimensional manifold (in the ordinary Euclidean sense).

Given a point $p\in M$ we define a *derivation* $D_p$ (at $p$) to be linear functional on the space of smooth functions of $M$ such that $D_p(fg) = f(p)D_p(g) + g(p)D_p(f)$.

For any $p\in M$, there is an open set $U_p\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ containing $p$, and an open set $V_p\subset \mathbb{R}^m$ containing $0$, together with a diffeomorphism $\varphi_p:V_p \to (U_p\cap M)$. We define $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}_p(f) = \partial_i (f\circ \varphi)(0)$. It is clear that $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}_p$ is a derivation at $p$. Note, this definition depends on the choice of a chart for $M$.

Fix $1\leq i\leq m$. Let us define a vector field $V$ on a manifold $M$ by, 
$$ V(p) = \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}_p $$ 
Where we make a pointwise choice of atlas for each $p$. Why is it true that $V(f)$ is a smooth function provided that $f$ is smooth?

(Note, in books vector fields are defined locally based on a chart instead of punctually. Wondering whether this one single consistent chart is really necessary to have a smooth vector field. )

Comment: In general, there is no reason that $V$ (and hence $V(f)$) will be smooth.  In fact, given any choice of tangent vector $V$ at every point (even a horribly discontinuous one), there is a choice of charts giving that $V$.

Comment: Is this why books define derivations on the whole patch as opposed to each point at a time? I been trying to prove smoothness for my punctual vector and I was unable to do it using the definitions. But I can easily do it using a local vector.

Comment: Well, if you just want single derivation at every a point, your method accomplishes that.  If you want some kind of smooth thing, then one way to accomplish this is by using the whole chart at once.  (Note that, in general, this only defines a vector field on a proper subset of the manifold.  At overlaps of charts, some care needs to be taken.)

Comment: Let us say the vector field is smooth so that $V(f)$ is a smooth function. If we write, $V(p) = \sum_i a_i(p) \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}_p$ does it follow then that the $a_i(p)$ are smooth functions (still writing each derivation  using a punctually choice).

Comment: If $V$ is a smooth vector field, I don't *think* it follows that the $a_i(p)$ are smooth, because the $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$ are defined by different charts at each point.  If $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$ instead refers to the $x_i$ coordinate on a single chart, then yes, it will follow that the $a_i$ are all smooth functions (and the converse also holds).